# NStimer and Dispatchqueue starts a little late when using the airpot

Tags: swift, timer, nstimer

My app provides voice to AVPlayer and gives a little term using Timer in the middle of playback so that users can read along.

It works well on simulators and real devices.

However, when you pair the air pot, the timer starts about 0.2 seconds late.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

I used 'Timer.scheduler' and 'Dispatchqueue.Main.asyncAfter', but both had the same symptoms.

Comment: @Rob Airpot is bluetooth earphone. Sorry for the confusion. The problem appears when I use Bluetooth earphones. 
The timer starts about 0.1 to 0.2 seconds late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gather that you are starting playback and simultaneously starting a timer, but when you do this with Bluetooth earphones, that they don’t seem in sync. If that’s the case, I might suggest not using your own timer, but rather let the `AVPlayer` tell you where it is.

For example, you might use [`addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval:queue:using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1385829-addperiodictimeobserver). The `AVPlayer` tell you when it got to a particular point in the playback.